# Have any RPGs ever been based on the world of William Blake?

Tags: game-recommendation

In William Blake's more famous poems, the highly detailed personal mythology he created is not evident. But in everything else he wrote, characters such as Los, Enitharmion, and Rintrah recur perpetually. Not only that, but a whole mythology of the creation of the world, in which "entering the void gave birth to Albion's lovely land," and "Los erected towers that stretched past the sky and re-arranged the magnetic poles," et cetera. Reading *Vala*, the unpublished sketchbook for all of these ideas, I have to ask myself, *Is this really the year 17XX?*

Has anyone made his world into an RPG?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dean Shomshak directly used the mythology from Blake's "Prophetic Books" -- the Four Zoas, *et al.* -- in **The Ultimate Super Mage**, a supplement for Champions/HERO 4E published in 1996.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any direct adaptations - however, as can be expected, Blake has inspired quite a number of game designers and rpg fans. Witness, for example, [Urizen as an Elder God for Call of Cthulhu](http://www.yog-sothoth.com/threads/563-The-Tygers-of-Wrath-are-Wiser-than-the-Horses-of-Instruction), or, another example, [an interview with John Wick](http://www.rpg.net/sf/interviews/wick99.html) about - among other things - how ***Seventh Sea* is based loosely on / inspired by the works of Blake**.

Answer (score 3):

In 1983, Avalon Hill released a RPG titled "Lords of Creation" with a rule book and a "Book of Foes". Within this set, part 8 "Lands of Wonder" the Land of Ulro was based on William Blake's work. The information includes diagrams and pictures of the world and characters.

http://thoulsparadise.blogspot.com/2018/01/role-playing-william-blake-way.html?m=1

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.